# How-to get the get_category_parents() breadcrumbs trail without link on last item

Tags: breadcrumb, link-category

Just a question : I want to use `get_category_parents()` to display a breadcrumb on a category archive page, but with no link on the current displayed category (SEO purposes, because they say that's a link to itself. I'm not sure search engines are *that* stupid, but anyway).

Like this :

> link_home » link_cat1 » link_subcat1 » nolink_subsubcat1

`get_category_parents()` is perfect for that, but there's only two options : with links and without links.

What I want is links BUT on the last item.

The function is returning a string, not a object or array, so I cannot remove the last item.

I could do with regex by searching with the `&raquo;` separator and remove last link that way, but i'm pretty bad with regexes (if you know good references for that, i'm interested !).

I know the obvious answer is to create a custom function using `get_ancestors()` and a loop , then simply adding after the current category name.

But I wanted to know is there is some more simplier way, but just hooking `get_category_parents()` to not adding link to the last item ?

Thank you for any insight.

Regards
Simon

Comment: Please take your time and format Qs properly.

Comment: Sorry Kaiser, what's Qs ?

Comment: Qs means Questions :D

Comment: Ok sorry, I didn't get the ` ` and > formating caracters. Will remember it for next time. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wouldn't consider this any better/worse than Kaiser's option, but just different. Why not use `get_category_parents` on the parent category and then (optionally) append the current category?

I haven't tested this, but something like the following should work:

```
$cat_id=7;//current category's ID (e.g. 7)
$separator='&raquo;';//The separator to use
$category = get_category($cat_id);//$category is the current category object
$parent_id = $category[0]->category_parent //category's parent ID
$ancestors = get_category_parents($parent_id, true, $separator);
```

Then optionally add the current category's name:

```
 if($ancestors){
      $breadcrumb = $ancestors.$separator.' <span class="active-cat">'.single_cat_title().'</span>';
 }else{
      $breadcrumb = '<span class="active-cat">'.single_cat_title().'</span>';
 }
     echo $breadcrumb;
```

#### EDIT:

It turns out this almost exactly how WordPress produces the output: `get_category_parents` calls itself recursively ([see here](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.3.1/wp-includes/category-template.php#L42)), so with this method you are essentially 'stopping it early', and manually completing it. There are no hooks that can achieve this effect however.

Comment: Working, with some minor changes (displaying the separator when `get_category_parents` returns a WP_error and using `get_category` instead of `get_the_category`). I could provide code in answer or editing question. Thank you very much. I appreciate the logical answer, should've thought of it...

Answer (score 3):

#### Use native php functions

It's not that hard, if you take a in-depth look at string/array handling on php.net.

```
// 1. Calls the category parents including their links
// 2. Explodes the string to an array with limit -1 to avoid outputting the last element
// 3. Loops through the array and echos the breadcrumbs
// 3.a Shows the » only after the first breadcrumb
foreach( explode( '//', get_category_parents( $cat, true, '//' ), -1 ) as $index => $breadcrumb )
    echo $index <= 0 ? $breadcrumb : " &raquo; {$breadcrumb}";
// 4. Echo the current category with a leading »
echo ' &raquo; <span class="breadcrumb-active-cat">'.single_cat_title().'</span>';
```

<sup>Note: Not tested</sup>

Comment: +1 Was just doing something very similar. You should change `get_the_category()` though - that's the category object rather than name...?

Comment: @StephenHarris As always: If you think you got something that makes the A better - feel free to edit.

Comment: Working, except not displaying sub categories but only current category. I'm not too familiar with this syntax so I'll go with Stephen answer, if you don't mind. But thank you, that was very close of what I have in mind.

Comment: @kaiser and stephen I loved both of your answer and noticed something and posted an answer, I would like to know if there is any problem in the way I have done it .

Comment: @StephenHarris sorry for this dirty comment, but was unable to tag you in my above comment.

Comment: @PrafullaKumarSahu - there's nothing wrong with it. In fact, it looks like it's the same as my answer, except you've assumed that the current item is returned is returned by `get_queried_object()` - which is *probably* a correct assumption. You've omitted the current item from the breadcrumb - the OP wanted it there, just without a link.

Comment: @StephenHarris thank you for your reply .I am using mine as it is little short :D thank you again.

Answer (score 1):

Though a bit old thread, I have come out with this:

```
$catpars= get_category_parents($cat_id, true, ' &raquo; ');
$catpars= preg_replace('/\W\w+\s*(\W*)$/', '', $catpars);
```

Answer (score 0):

In a category page you can also do and it will leave current category from the breadcrumb and all its parent categories will be displayed.

```
   echo get_category_parents( get_queried_object()->parent, true, ' &rarr; ' );
```